# Gerenciar erros em chamadas HTTP

Tags: php, angular

Estou trabalhando em uma aplicação com Angular(4+) e PHP e estou com algumas dúvidas a respeito das chamadas HTTP feitas ao servidor e como melhor o gerenciamento dos casos em que a função retorna com erro.

Atualmente possuo esse código (em JS/Angular) para efetuar as chamadas:

```
createUser(user: any): any {
    return this._http.post(this.backendUrl, user).map(response => {
        console.log('Mensagem de sucesso: ', response);
    }).catch(this.handleErrors);
}

handleErrors(error: Response): any {
    console.log('Gerenciar erro: ', error);
}
```

Para exemplificar melhor a situação, suponha que eu possua uma função, em PHP, para efetuar a criação de um novo usuário, onde antes de criar o usuário propriamente dito, eu preciso verificar algumas condições, como e-mail único, campos obrigatórios preenchidos, etc..

Atualmente o que eu faço é verificar essas condições e retornar uma resposta em JSON, por exemplo:

```
$param = [':email' => $email];
$check = sql("SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE email = :email", $param);
if ( $check ) {
    return print_r(json_encode(array(
        'success' => 0,
        'message' => 'Este email já está registrado'
    ), JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK));
}
```

Neste caso, apesar de haver um "erro" durante a execução da função, fazendo com que ela seja interrompida antes de criar um usuário, ela é tratada como um função que retornou com sucesso. Para esse tipo de caso eu preciso verificar o conteúdo da mensagem de erro, assim:

```
return this._http.post(this.backendUrl, user).map(response => {
    console.log('Mensagem de sucesso: ', response);

    if(!response.success) {
        return alert(response.message);
    }

    lista_usuario.unshift(response.usuario); // Supondo que o usuário tenha sido criado
}).catch(this.handleErrors);
```

Este método está funcionando, porém, como vocês podem observar, para cada função que eu chamo (existem outros casos semelhantes), eu preciso verificar se o conteúdo retornado como `success` é de fato um retorno válido ou um erro.

---

O que eu tentei fazer foi interromper a função utilizando:

```
throw new Execption('mensagem aqui');
```

O problema com este método é que ainda assim a resposta retorna é um `success`, porém com mensagem de `null` e o único local que consigo visualizar a mensagem de erro é abrindo o console e inspecionando a chamada na aba de `network`.

O que eu gostaria de fazer é interromper e retornar a função `PHP` de modo que seja possível tratar esses erros dentro do *callback* de erro, no meu exemplo, dentro da função `handleErrors`. Sendo assim, apenas as funções que realmente executarem todo o processo serão retornadas com sucesso.

Comment: Sua premissa me parece bem errada. Exceções devem ser usadas para casos excepcionais e não para tratamento de regras de validação.

Comment: @LINQ era o que eu imaginava, mas não conheço tanto de PHP para saber se é possível obter esse resultado, ou qual seria o melhor método de fazer o tratamento desses dados/funções. Na verdade eu não preciso ficar preso a um método, o importante é o resultado final, ou o que for mais "correto", se é que pode ser dito isso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui "resolver" o problema utilizando o seguinte código:

```
// No início do código, para retornar status 500 em qualquer erro não esperado.
ini_set('display_errors', 0);

// Antes de retornar uma função
http_response_code(401); // ou outro código. 404, 409, 420, etc...
```

Como não entendo muito de `PHP`, vou deixar a questão ainda em aberto para uma possível melhor opção para o problema.